# 2-D Array not changing value inside While loop

Tags: java, arrays, sudoku

For some reason, the 2D instance integer array is not changing its variable's value to 0 inside the while loop. board is another 2D int array with a complete sudoku board, solve_1 solves sudoku by starting to test from 1 to 9, and solve_2 from 9 to 1 by backtrack method, both working correctly. So, if there are more than 1 solutions, both methods' 2D array outputs model_1 and model_2 will differ.
2D array puzzle stores the last unique sudoku grid. print method outputs the array, but not one square changes to 0 though the loop undergoes infinite iterations without stackoverflowing, i.e. reaches the commented line but does not change any int to 0. The line works outside the loop, of course only once then.

```
private void makePuzzle() {
    model = board;
    int row, col;
    while (Arrays.deepEquals(model_1, model_2)) {
        puzzle = model;
        row = r.nextInt(9);
        col = r.nextInt(9);
        model[row][col] = 0; //this line is problematic
        solve1(0, 0);
        solve2(0, 0);
        System.out.println(row+" "+col);
        print(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your full code ?

Comment: This `model = board` and `puzzel = model` looks suspicious to me. Know that this does not make a copy of the `int[]`, just a reference. The 3 variables will point to the same object.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee seems to have cleared my basic misconception. Will update if it works. If you post this as an answer, I will select it. But I still don't understand why model cannot be changed, if model is changed board should also change, right? Why are they both immutable inside the while but not outside?

Comment: I can not give a real answer unless you show more of your code. Preferably a [mcve]. You say you still don't understand some things, perhaps I could answer those too then.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand it very well, but I believe the problem is that you should be passing the board value as a parameter in the method, as in makePuzzle(board)

Unless you make the board variable global, it should not have values inside the method. Because java considers the inner board is not the same as the outer board

Comment: "Unless you make the board variable global, it should not have values inside the method".  well if this statement ---> model = board; is not giving a compilation error then "board" is global to the class.

Comment: All the variables except row and col are global.